# Mapbox custom SVG marker and color property

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to specify a custom SVG for markers and still use the color property ?
I imagine that the SVG should respect a specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only way to be able to apply colours to images dynamically within Mapbox is with SDF images.

See https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/using-recolorable-images-in-mapbox-maps/ .